# The regenerator/runtime module is deprecated

Tags: react-native

I got an error when running on iOS device, but no error on simulator.

I tried delete"node_modules" reinstall and recreate project still got this:

```
2016-08-12 18:50:59.247 [warn][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] The regenerator/runtime module is deprecated; please import regenerator-runtime/runtime instead.
2016-08-12 18:50:59.604 [error][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] Can't find variable: Symbol
2016-08-12 18:50:59.608 [fatal][tid:com.facebook.React.RCTExceptionsManagerQueue] Unhandled JS Exception: Can't find variable: Symbol
2016-08-12 18:50:59.619 [info][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] Running application "Qtq" with appParams: {"rootTag":1,"initialProps":{}}. __DEV__ === true, development-level warning are ON, performance optimizations are OFF
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what version of RN? Is it possible to view project code?

Comment: In previous versions of react-native, some code changes were done to have the bundle locally within the app.

Comment: "react-native": "^0.21.0"